# Highlight selected row without altering colors in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to highlight the currently selected row on an Excel sheet with a pattern. (Not a color because some cells on that row might be colored already.)

I have written the following VBA macro. When a new cell is selected, it resets the whole sheet's colors.

It would be ok if it cleared the whole patterns on the sheet (because no cells are formatted with a pattern) but, even if I specify to clear only the pattern (using `ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternNone`), it also clears the colors and borders.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'remove past colors
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternNone
    With Me
        .Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Pattern = XlPattern.xlPatternChecker
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the default setting for font/fill/etc.?  That would allow you to clearly change only the particular parameters desired.  Also, ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior refers to the entire sheet.  You will need to specify the range you're intending to work in.

Comment: Additionally, you could set-up a conditional formatting which activates on Change Event... my thought would be on cell selection the active row would have some value in column 1, so the conditional format formula, applied by the Change Event colors all (arbitrarily) of that rows fill to light blue, which doesn't change the base colors.  Your change event conditional formatting would start with removing conditional formatting, then applying what you want for the activerow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xlPatternAutomatic` instead of `xlPatternNone`. Note, howver, that it will also remove the grid (but not borders that you added).